# Creating tables in html

Tags: html

how do i make a table like this?

```
abc |la
sa  |___
cdef|hi
```

basically the borders like that

Comment: Is that `___` a horizontal border?

Comment: You're going to have to do some inline styles on the <td>s or use some funky CSS classes.  Either way it's going to be ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want one high cell next to two smaller ones. That can be achieved with the `rowspan` attribute like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">abc sa cdef</td>
    <td>la</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix would be the following:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">abc</td>
        <td class="right1">la</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">sa</td>
        <td class="right2">&nbps;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">cdef</td>
        <td class="right1">hi</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
td.left { border-right:1px solid black; }
td.right2 { border-bottom:1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td class="border-r"> abc </td>
 <td> la </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="border-r"> sa </td>
 <td class="border-b">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="border-r">cdef</td>
 <td> hi </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

css

```
td.border-r
{
 border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
td.border-b
{
 border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="border-r"> abc </td>
 <td> la </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="border-r"> sa </td>
 <td class="border-b">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="border-r">cdef</td>
<td> hi </td>
```